# Is Control-Enter a generally accepted shortcut to mean "Accept" on Windows?

Tags: windows, user-interface

I'm developing a desktop app on Windows, and am currently binding the "Control-Enter" key to the "accept" command on dialogs and view/edit fields. It seems to me that this is a fairly common meaning to this key binding, for example, a number of websites (Facebook, Twitter) use it to mean "submit" in form entry, and programs like TortoiseSvn and TortoiseHg use it to accept dialogs and changeset message entry fields.

This meaning was challenged however, and now I'm looking for the UI guideline which might be the source of this seemingly common binding. Is there one, or has it been adopted by ad-hoc convention?

EDIT: To clarify, the cases I'm specifically talking about is where "Enter" is used as a valid input character in the text. The text entry fields in Facebook and in the commit message fields accept enter, so it is not used to accept the dialog or submit the form in those cases, but "Ctrl+Enter" is.

EDIT 2: You yourselves can try it here by pressing "Enter" in the text field for questions and answers and then pressing "Ctrl+Enter".

Comment: In my experience, `ENTER` by itself usually means "accept" or "OK".  Can you give an example where `Control-ENTER` works but `ENTER` by itself doesn't?

Comment: You can make Ctrl+Enter mean anything you like.  A user will however never guess it means "accept".  He'll press the Enter key instead.  Make sure you don't ignore it.

Comment: Well the examples I gave are a good start, but it seems that any time you find where enter is accepted as a valid input character is a good general guideline.

Comment: @HansPassant - unless, of course, Enter means "insert newline in the text here" which is the case I'm talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft has its [Windows User Experience Interaction Guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa511258.aspx) (conveniently downloadable as a PDF document) that only describes this keystroke as an address bar shortcut:

> Ctrl+Enter Add "h ttp://www." to the beginning and ".com" to the end of text in Address bar.

So far for the "official" source.

However, as is so often the case, Microsoft's own programs ([eg Outlook](http://www.zeigen.com/shortcuts/2007/06/11/send-email/)) go beyond these guidelines and also use <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>enter</kbd> to signal "Okay,we're done here".

In my opinion the fact that it's not sanctioned by any publication isn't that important, as you already pointed out several programs already use the shortcut in the same sense you do, including one of Microsoft's flagship products - so I'd say go for it.